# Google Sheets Import Range Error: Showing different values from source sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have been successfully importing data from a source sheet using the import range function. Today, for the same import range, some of the values being imported are different from those on the source sheet, and some of the values are being displayed as NAs.

For example:

```
Source Sheet values (1,2,3,4,5)

Import Range Sheet values (1,2,6,NA,NA)
```

Not sure if this is a new bug because the import range has been working fine till now.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: My guess is that you aren't *just* using IMPORTRANGE, but rather that you are processing the data coming in with additional formula components. It's also possible that you have random cells' formatting in different formats, which can display equivalent data in different ways. The only way we can assess any of that, as player0 has suggested, is if we have full access to the spreadsheet.